How to get Overlapping time in Power BI
I have a bunch of jobs that run on daily basis but at different timings. Now I need to know which jobs run parallely and results in overlap.
An example for the same would be like
| Job Name | Start time | | End Time    |
| -------- | ---------- | | ----------- |
| A        | 08:30:01 PM| | 09:41:05 PM |
| B        | 09:00:00 PM| | 09:02:14 PM |
| C        | 09:30:01 PM| | 09:30:11 PM |
| D        | 10:00:00 PM| | 10:05:07 PM |
| E        | 10:30:00 PM| | 10:36:56 PM |
| F        | 10:45:01 PM| | 10:56:50 PM |

So I should get the result
Overlap in A and B, A and C, E and F. With the duration and time of overlap as in A and B -> 09:00:00 PM| | 09:02:14 PM and 00:02:14 as result and for the rest as well
I looked here and there and tried using Gemini and Chatgpt as well but can't find the solution so Pls help

Can you share your data model ? some input and clear output ?

is there something wrong with your raw data?
why E and F are overlapped? F starts after E ends.
So i modify your raw data
you can try to create a column
Column=
VAR _time = [ Start time ]
VAR _time2 = 'Table'[End Time]
VAR _last =
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[ Start time ] < _time && 'Table'[End Time] > _time ),
        'Table'[ Start time ]
    )
VAR _list =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        DISTINCT ( 'Table'[Job Name] ),
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[ Start time ] > _time
                && 'Table'[ Start time ] < _time2
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( _last ), CONCATENATEX ( _list, [Job Name], "," ), BLANK () )


